# Autofac register dll using Assembly.Load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, autofac

I'm trying to register a dll named "BigEye.Business" and referenced that file to the mvc 3 project. But when i try to get instance of an object in that dll, autofac says it's not registered. Here is how i register and resolve the object:

```
private static IContainer SetDIContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterType<UserAuthManager>().As<IUserAuth>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<SessionManager>().As<ISession>().InstancePerHttpRequest();


            //Here is the code to register that dll
            var services = Assembly.Load("BigEye.Business");
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services);
            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

            return container;
        }

        public static T GetInstance<T>()
        {
            IContainer container = SetDIContainer();

            using(var httpRequestScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("httpRequest"))
            {
                return httpRequestScope.Resolve<T>();
            }

        }
```

And when i call GetInstance function i get "The requested service 'BigEye.Interfaces.Business.IUser' has not been registered". Should i register all the components in Business dll? Is there a way to do it? Because objects and services in Business will change in time.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just add a reference to your dll in the project?

Comment: Well i can do that but i want to inject it...

Comment: That's what `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services);` is supposed to do, isn't it? I'd try stepping into that if you can to work out what that line is actually doing. Do you have any inheritance between your assemblies, i.e. can you add a reference to the assembly that defines the interfaces that your business assembly implements at least?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that your assembly contains one or more implementations of the `IUser` interface. Now, when you run:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services);
```

without any additional parameters you are actually registering all types in that assembly *keyed by class*. You will probably see that this resolve works:

```
GetInstance<SomeSpecificUserImplementation>();
```

In order to key your services *by interface*, simply do the following:

```
  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Now all your services will be keyed by the interfaces they implement instead of the specific class, thus the following will work:

```
GetInstance<IUser>();
```